# Where water will be on a mudflat as tide comes in/goes out?

Tags: hydrology, aerial-photography

My study area is large intertidal mudflat in NE England. I want know where the water will be depending on tide height. The attached shows an aerial of my study area. I've photoshopped in the blue lines to show the type of information I need, therefore where the water will be depending on water height as the tide comes in/goes out. Is this data available anywhere?[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the Open Lidar data available from the Environment Agency. It's got good coverage for England (at least in coastal and river areas - anywhere at risk of flooding, basically).

In your case ([OS Grid NU14](http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/survey/index.jsp#/survey?grid=NU14)), available at 1m resolution. You might want neighbouring tiles too. Depending on location these are available at 2m, 1m and sometimes 0.5m/pixel resolution, and as rasters or point clouds.

Be sure to read the [Technical specs too](https://ea.sharefile.com/share?#/view/saf45292b4f6482b8)... note the vertical accuracy is +/- 0.15m worst-case, in which case you might struggle to get accurate 0.1m contours as shown in your screenshot. Also, the data could be a few years old.. given how fast some parts of the coast are silting up, or being eroded, that could be an issue too...

You don't say which tools you're using, but here's what I'd do in QGIS:-

- extract the downloaded zip file to a folder
- use **Raster > Miscellaneous > Merge** (and point it to your folder). This will merge the individual ASCII tiles together into one image (you may need to manually edit the command line to output to tiff, if you get an error about "_____ format does not support writing")
- set the combined image layer CRS to epsg:27700.
- colour it using range -5 to 30 so you can see what you're working with
- use Contours to generate required contour lines (-9999 means 'no data')

The contours tool looked like it was going to take forever, so I gave up and used raster style instead.

Here's an example, done using the 2m/pixel resolution. I've shown any pixels between 1.1m and 1.2m in red.. anything higher or lower is transparent.

[image]

Note that a large chunk of the bay shows as below sea level, and there are some artifacts - the technical specs I linked to explains why these happen.

Heights are [above Ordnance Datum Newlyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_datum) so should be relative to mean sea level.

Hope that points you in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you look at the [Channel Coastal Observatory](http://www.channelcoast.org/) website, there is a wealth of archival and real time data to download, including lidar.